# I have a rooted Android 14 - I want to share its VPN connection with a printer

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, vpn, openvpn

I originally thought what I am trying to do is extremely simple, but for the past few hours, I discovered it really isn't.

I have a rooted Pixel 7 running Android 14 in a remote storage unit. In that same storage unit, there is a printer with a camera that can only be connected to using LAN. My goal is to be able to connect to the printer and watch the feed from my computer at home.

I have an Asus RT-AX82U router that can be used as a PPTP\OpenVPN\IPSec\WireGuard server.

I thought - great - I will just set my router as an OpenVPN server, connect to that server from my Pixel, share the Pixel connection with the printer, and connect my PC to the same VPN.

But unfortunately, I couldn't get the printer to get the VPN connection - it was just getting the regular LTE connection.

What did I do wrong?